# populate DTO from queryparam using Restlet

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I have multiple query params and i want to populate the dto from them. Is there any way to do so.

This is what i have now:

```
public Response getInfo(@QueryParam("A") String a, @QueryParam("B") String b, @QueryParam("C") String c, ){
.....
}
```

This is what i want to do:

```
public Response getInfo(InputDTO inputDto){
.....
}

public class InputDTO {
private String a;
private String b;
private String c;
//... getters and setters
}
```

Please help.
Restlet version : 2.3.4